# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle - Problem

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

There was a question in my exam discrete maths that I just couldn't figure out. I know it's supposed to be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle. anyone able to help me solve and understand this question.

For a survey, 200 people are asked about which forms of transport the had used in the last month it was found that

150 used trains,

80 had cycled and used trains, and

180 had used one or the other of these two forms of transport.

Question: How many people had cycled in the last month?

Question: How many had not used either form of transport.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried?

Comment: See [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for the first Question. Use subtraction for the second one.

Comment: Do you know Venn diagrams?

Comment: Yes, I know Venn Diagrams that's how I got my answer I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LET  $c$ and $t$ denote cycle and train.

$$ c \cup  t =180$$
$$c \cap t +80$$

$$ t=150$$ $$180= c +150 -80 $$

$$c=110 $$

Those who did not use any of the two transportations are

$$200-180 =20$$

Comment: Wow, thank you for that I get it now.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.